# Setup default gateway with two "hops"

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, gateway

My IT dept seem to have given me a really strange setup and I can't quite figure out what I need to do, though I think I have an idea which I need help to setup (if possible):

My PC (Ubuntu 14.04) IP address/network is:
network: 172.30.2.64
mask:    255.255.255.192

IT tell me that my default gateway is: 192.130.6.177

So, all my PCs have addresses in 172.30.2.64/26 range and can ping each other.
I can't ping the default gateway - infact I get a `Network is unreachable` error.

So, I guessed maybe there is a router sat at 172.30.2.65 (effectively x.x.x.1 on my network). I can ping this address and so I added this as my default gateway:

`sudo route add -net 0.0.0.0 gw 172.30.2.65`

Now I am able to ping the "IT default gateway" (192.130.6.177).

The next problem is that I need my traffic to flow through this gateway (192.130.6.177), which I can only access via 172.30.2.65 gateway... I am so confused!

So I think I need to set my PC up like this:

`My PC --> 172.30.2.65 --> 192.130.6.177 --> External internet`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IT department gave you the wrong information.  Your analysis is correct, and your default gateway should be 172.30.2.65.  The final hop before the internet is 192.130.6.177 by the sounds of it, so this is the default route out of the network.  It is not a private address which is odd, but not uncommon.

The fact that you can ping this address from your network suggests the routing to this device is working.  It is possible that this is not the last hop to the internet, in which case there may be another router on the internal network beyond this one that is unaware of your network and so cannot route back to you.

If not, the most likely scenario is that this router has not been:

1. Configured to NAT your address range to a public address that can traverse the internet
2. Configured to permit your range access to the internet

Could be (1), (2) or both, or something more esoteric, but in any case, they will need to resolve it, it is likely that you won't be able to resolve this by changing anything on your end.

Comment: ahh, ok. I was starting to think it might be something their end : (
Thanks for information and pointing me in the right direction! : )